# Bialeti Brikka with Silver vs Black Bottom

Tags: moka

I ordered the Bialetti Brikka off of Amazon, the new one I think with the silver bottom:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008G48DW4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008G48DW4)

But I received one that looks like this with the black bottom:

[https://www.amazon.com/Bialetti-Brikka-Limited-Edtion-Bottom/dp/B07F3SMMYD/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=bialetti+brikka&qid=1568493637&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F3SMMYD)

that one is listed as cheaper and is I think an older model. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a question for consumer advice rather than a coffee q&a.
 From what i can see you have 2 options :

1 - Keep the model they have sent and ask for a refund for the difference in price
2 - Return the model they have sent and wait for them to send the correct model

The links you provided are pretty vague but they appear to be the exact same just a variation in colour, with the black being sold as a limited edition, I'm not sure why the limited edition would be cheaper though, normally words like that are marketed to increase price.

Answer (score 1):

The black one is the newer model with a slightly different water scale indicator in the top, otherwise identical.